# SQL Query not finding all rows in SUM and COUNT

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
select coalesce(ratings.positive,0) as positive,coalesce(ratings.negative,0) as negative,articles.id,x.username,commentnumb, 
    articles.category,
    articles."createdAt",
    articles.id,
    articles.title,
    articles."updatedAt"
    FROM articles
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id AS userId,username,about FROM users) x ON articles.user_id = x.userId
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,
        article_id,
        sum(case when rating = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as positive,
        sum(case when rating = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as negative
        from article_ratings
        GROUP by id
        ) as ratings ON ratings.article_id = articles.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT article_id,id,
       count(article_id) as commentNumb
       from article_comments
       GROUP by id
       ) as comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id
    WHERE articles."createdAt" <= :date
    group by ratings.positive,ratings.negative,articles.id,x.username,commentnumb
    order by articles."createdAt" desc
    LIMIT 10
```

The code is working, however I have many more comments and many more ratings than what is counted in both SUM and COUNT functions.

How do I fix this query?

This is using postgres.

I've done some experimentation and it seems that the third join for comments is the one causing issues.

Comment: Are there any null values in either the article_ratings or article_comments table?

Comment: This could also be a join problem - since you are grouping by the LEFT JOIN, you are filtering out records in the `articles` table.

Comment: @RSax no null values

Comment: @RSax It's a join problem, since that's all Im doing anyway. But I have no other option except to left join. This also works with only 1 entry. If I change the where clause to equal an ID. It works for 1 entry.

Comment: I see you are selecting article_id in 2 of your select, but not in the group_by. My MySQl allows that behavior, but could it be that?  Also try distincting your first select to see if that helps.

Comment: @Meckel'sDiverticulum doesn't work mate. Tried doing that, this is for postgresql btw. Feel like I should mention that.

Comment: I removed the third left join, the article_comments. If I don't remove that part, it doesn't return the right results. I also removed the aggregate functions outside of the joins, which seems to work. However, this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the derived tables, you should ideally be grouping using article_id. But, you are grouping based on id. Due to this, you are getting more than the necessary rows in the derived tables. I have modified the query to suit your needs.

```sql
    SELECT COALESCE(ratings.positive,0) AS positive,COALESCE(ratings.negative,0) AS negative,articles.id,x.username,commentnumb, 
        articles.category,
        articles."createdAt",
        articles.id,
        articles.title,
        articles."updatedAt"
        FROM articles
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id AS userId,username,about FROM users) x ON articles.user_id = x.userId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT article_id,
            SUM(case when rating = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as positive,
            SUM(case when rating = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as negative
            FROM article_ratings
            GROUP by article_id 
            ) AS ratings ON ratings.article_id = articles.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT article_id,
           count(article_id) as commentNumb
           FROM article_comments
           GROUP by article_id
           ) AS comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id
        WHERE articles."createdAt" <= :date
        ORDER BY articles."createdAt" desc
        LIMIT 10;
```